# left outer join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am implementing a left outer join with the customer table and am joining it with the payroll table. I am having trouble with Oracle recognizing that I only want the employees that are not current on their audits.

```
SELECT e.E_Name, e.Phone
FROM E_Name.Employee AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN E_Name.Payroll AS p
ON e.E_Name = p.E_Name
WHERE p.audit != 'current';
```

My error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: What is `E_Name` here? `E_Name.Payroll` might be the problem.

Comment: is `E_Name` a schema or a column? You are using it as both!  Is that right ?

Comment: While it's not relevant to the central problem, having `p.audit != 'current'` in the `where` clause will implicitly convert the outer join to an inner join.

Comment: E_Name is a column in both Employee and Payroll. Would an inner join be more efficient?

Comment: Inner join and outer join have different meanings, it's not only a matter of efficiency... It would be  easier to help if you could post the structure of your tables, your data and an example of the result you need

Comment: You resolved the issue. I understand now that I had mistakenly put my column names before the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have columns with the same name of your schema (`E_Name`), you simply have to remove the `as`:

```
SELECT e.E_Name, e.Phone
FROM Employee  e
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payroll  p
ON e.E_Name = p.E_Name
WHERE p.audit != 'current';
```

Comment: When I run that it says, the table doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems that your problem is not the query, but the table names; does `select * from E_Name.Payroll` work? and `select * from E_Name.Employee` ? Just edited, try it now

Comment: No those flagged an error as well. So would it be better to exclude the "column_name.table" part of the join?

Comment: the syntax is `SELECT COLUMS FROM TABLES`...; having the name of a column preceding the name of a table in a `FROM` clause makes no sense: the `FROM` indicates the TABLES you need, while in the `SELECT` part you write the columns you need to extract

Comment: Okay that makes sense